# Normal extension, why $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)/\mathbb Q$ is not normal and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)/\mathbb Q$ is normal.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Normal extension, why $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)/\mathbb Q$ is not normal and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)/\mathbb Q$ is normal where $\zeta_3=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$. My definition of normal extension is $L/K$ is normal if $$\text{Hom}_K(L,K^{alg})=\text{Aut}_K(L),$$
but I don't hide you that I can't apply it, it's too abstract for me.

Comment: Non-abstract approach: count both sides.

Comment: How ? I don't see how you can count all the homomorphism.

Comment: To count homomorphisms, remember that $\mathbb Q$ should not move. So, you just have to decide where to send $\sqrt[3]{2}$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$: how many possibilities do you have, **so that the defined map is a morphism of fields** ? Apply the same kind of thinking to count automorphisms on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building up to your definition, an extension $N/K$ is normal when the image of every $K$-homomorphism of the extension $N$ is contained in $N$ i.e. $\sigma(N) \subseteq N$ for a $K$-homomorphism $\sigma$. Since $\sigma$ is an injective ring homomorphism between the fields $N\to N$, we must have that $\sigma(N)\cong N$ since $\sigma (N)$ is a subspace of $N$ with equal dimension. Therefore $\sigma$ is an automorphism.

By properties of $K$-homomorphisms, we know that a $K$-homomorphism $\sigma$ will send an algebraic element to its conjugates over $K$. But in this case we have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ does not contain the conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so it's image does not lie in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and therefore it is not normal.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't want to use your definition but my definition. My definition says $L/K$ is normal if $Hom_K(L,K^{alg})=Aut_K(L)$, so I have to count those homomorphism.

Comment: one sec let me revise my answer

Comment: @Rick: I think it's a good answer, and you can easily adapt it to what you are looking for.

Comment: An automorphism maps a root of $x^3-2$ to another root. If there is no other root, there is only one automorphism. However since there are $3$ roots in  $K^{\text{alg}}$, there  are $3$ $K$-morphisms from $L$ into $K^{\text{alg}}$.

Comment: alright just fixed it for ya.